# How can I make the keyboard of other text field disappear while accessing other text field

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I have two text fields in my view. I did it using IB. in second text field i am using the action sheet

After entering the text in textField1 I am in text Field-2.In second text field i am using the action sheet with a picker to select the date. so i resigned the textfield -2 keyboard before opening the action sheet. after i dismiss the action sheet when i tried to resign the keyboard  it is not returning. 
i used

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textfield1 resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

to resign the textfield1 ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
   //don't forget to add <UITextFieldDelegate> in your .h
   firstTextField.delegate=self;
   secondTextField.delegate=self;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if(textField.tag==2)
    {
      //Here you can call function to view your datepicker
      return NO; //Will not open keyboard for second textfield.
    }
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have return current textField textFieldShouldReturn method change your textFieldShouldReturn metod like below

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set tag to every text fields and check them in

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if([textfield.tag == 1])
   {
       [textFieldFirst resignFirstResponder];
   }
   else
   {
     // your action sheet code here
   }
   return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to Give the tag for TextField,

Within this method,

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{              
    if (textField.tag == 2)
    {
       [textField1 resignFirstResponder];
       // your action sheet code here 
    } 
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField           
{
   [textfield resignFirstResponder]
   return YES;
}
```

Comment: with out returning the 1st text field keyboard i am passing to 2nd one . the text field for the 2nd field is not opening as i resigned it as first responder ..but keyboard of the 1st field is not resigning@